# Could hadoop let mapper send partial data to reducer, and output the remaining data to HDFS directly?

Tags: hadoop

As the title said, I have a task design about map-reduce:

After thinking, I thought that only partial data (may 10% data) need to be sent into the reducer, the remaining data just output to HDFS directly. Then in the end, I just combine these two outputs file from mapper and reducer (I must get a unified file or directory about this total data). I think,  by doing this, it can reduce the the bandwidth cost for this task running.

So can my thought implement? (I know how to output to HDFS from mapper directly, but this require mapper both output to HDFS and send data to reducer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use [MultipleOutputs's write() method](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28KEYOUT,%20VALUEOUT,%20java.lang.String%29) for 90% of the files and for the remaining 10% you can use the normal `context.write()` from the mapper, so that, they goes to the reducer only.

This function from MultipOutputs can be used -

```
void write(K key, V value, String baseOutputPath);
```

Second solution would be to use [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) (from Hadoop Api) directly for the Mapper to output 90% of the files to HDFS. But I don't know how efficient it would be if you are running lot of mappers. Same goes with MultipleOutput above -

Something like:

In the *setup()* function of mapper do this -

```
FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());
FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(new Path("your_hdfs_filename"));
```

While inside the *map()* function do this -

*create()* function would return you a FSDataOutputStream object. Use the *write(*) function to write to the file.

Close the FileSystem object in the *cleanup()* function after you are done.
Something like - `fs.close();`

Comment: if I use the MultipleOuputs, I want 90% data output to HDFS be key-> type1 value-> type2, and the 10% data going into the reduce, has the key -> type3 value->type3. So Can I implement this with different key value types?  @JtheRocker

Comment: @JoJo, Yup, that's possible too.